# Use of "in comparison to"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I have doubts regarding the construction of the phrase:

> "[...] degree of fulfilment regarding the number of water quality
>   parameters effectively controlled in comparison to the mandated number
>   of parameters to be controlled."

Do I need to include **to be controlled** at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to include that at the end if you are making a distinction between "controlling" parameters and "effectively controlling" parameters. It doesn't make sense if there is no semantic difference.

Taking this a step further, I suggest rewording the sentence so the two comparisons are similarly constructed.

> "[…] degree of fulfillment regarding the number of water quality parameters effectively controlled in comparison to the number of parameters mandated to be controlled."

That uses the first structure and reflects it in the second. The following uses the second structure and assumes a particular definition of "effectively" to reduce ambiguity.

> "[…] degree of fulfillment regarding the effective number of water quality parameters controlled in comparison to the mandated number of parameters to be controlled."

In the second example, you can then drop "of parameters to be controlled" without losing clarity.

> "[…] degree of fulfillment regarding the effective number of water quality parameters controlled in comparison to the mandated number."